# How to define previous in Rails for a different model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

Rails has in default `.next`. Is there `.previous` method in ruby, should i define it myself?

`"#{photo.id.previous}"`

I have it defined in my Photo model and it works for my photo views, but this is being used in the User views. Does it need to be defined in the User Model?

**users_controller.rb**

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @photos = @user.photos.order('created_at desc').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
end
```

**show.html.erb (users)**

```
<% @photos.in_groups_of(3, false).each do |group| %>
    <div class="row">
      <% group.each do |photo| %>
        <a data-toggle="modal" href=<%="#"+"#{photo.id}"%>>
          <div class="col-xs-4 insta">
            <%= image_tag(photo.picture.ad.url, class: "img-responsive") %>
          </div>
        </a>  
        <div class="modal" id=<%="#{photo.id}"%> tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
          </button>
...
...
...

<a class="prev" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" href=<%="#"+"#{photo.id.previous}"%>>
  "Previous"
</a>
<a class="next" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" href=<%="#"+"#{photo.id.next}"%>>
   "Next"
</a>
```

**user.rb**

```
def previous 
  #.. ?
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User
  def previous
    self.class.where("id < ?", id).last
  end
end

class User
  def next
    self.class.where("id > ?", id).first
  end
end

href=<%="#"+"#{photo.previous.id}"%>>

href=<%="#"+"#{photo.previous.id}"%>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find this record like this:

```
class User
  def self.previous_by_id(id)
    where("id < ?", id).last
  end
end

User.previous_by_id(5)
#=> #<User:0x0000000741b818 id: 4 .....>
```

Or if you want to define it like instance method:

```
class User
  def previous
    self.class.where("id < ?", id).last
  end
end
```

Comment: I haven't got it to work yet. What am I changing `"#{photo.id.previous}"` to? Thanks.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss just photo.previous if you use second case

Comment: this is still not working for me. I need what is inside of the curly brackets to return an integer. this returns #<Phooto:0x007f0438526e10> . Thanks

Comment: I figured it out. It is "#{photo.previous.id}"

Comment: If you edit your answer I will accept it as the correct answer. The instance variable I was using `@photos = @user.photos` is not isolating `:photo_id` `{photo.previous}` is just pulling the entire photo instance of the previous photo from the database selected by it's :id but not returning it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ruby already has this method. For eg:

```
1.pred
# => 0
```

Check out [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-next) for more detail

And Rails also supports this. For eg:

```
photo.id.pred
```

Comment: OP means ActiveRecord method, not Integer.

Comment: @llya: Did you try it? :D

Comment: what about case if i already delete record with `id = 5`, and you use this on record with `id = 6`?

Comment: I tested this and it does not work if a photo was deleted.

Comment: Yeah, that is right, comparing to photo.id.next, rails provided photo.id.pred, you may use @Ilya suggestion to implement both of your prev & next :)